# Admob Ads is not showing up

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

Okay I made a lot of research before I came here (sorry for my english).

My problem is : I made an application and I implement Admob 4.3.1 (my application is developped on Android 3.2 (with eclipse).

First time I was having the error "You must have INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission, I put them on my AndroidManifest.xml, now all is okay but when I start my application, my ads are not showing up.

I hope you can help me soon... thank you very much.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="test.package.sound"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/gg"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".testpackagesound"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".test1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".test2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".test3"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/image"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="test1"
    android:textColor="#005113" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="test2"
    android:textColor="#970000" />





<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="test3"
    android:textColor="#001760" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dip" >

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxx"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>


</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:fillViewport="true" >
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="300px"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/button4"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="test4" />
   <Button
android:id="@+id/button18"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="test18" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The code looks ok; I don't think the SDK uses the ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID, but that shouldn't have any affect.  Check the logcat output and see what kind of messages the SDK is giving you.

Answer (score 0):

So basically the only thing I can think of is that you missed something in your layout.xml file. Here's some example that might help you:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   //............Some other views
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                       ads:adUnitId="Your Add ID"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER" 
                       ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
   //Some other views
```

If I'm not wrong you either forgot line 3 or you don't have a correct add id. Hope this helps you.

If this doesn't help you take a look over the [official android addmob documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html) or maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899767/admob-error-in-eclipse-for-androidconfigchanges/7899849#7899849).

Also I hope you imported your AddMob libray to your project.

Comment: still not working, can i send you my layout ? cause i can not post it here because i am a new member.

Comment: Ok just click edit on your question and put it in the end it's easier.

Comment: it's done. thank you a lot... i am trying to find a solution of this issue from 4 days now...

Comment: Check if you imported the admob library. Also you seem to have a duplicate of this lines xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" keep them just in your base,first linearlayout.

Comment: Google AdMob ads SDK 4.3.1 is in my referenced librairies into my project... i deleted the duplicates lines now... same problem. is there any problem on the Site & apps website of Admobs ? i have to configure something on that ?

Comment: I don't think so. Don't you get any problems message,or anything in the errorLog? If not, the only thing I can think of is your id you put instead of XXXXXXXX is not good. This is as much as I can think of.

Comment: no i get nothing on errorlog... Ok then i have to re-create the apps on Admobs ? After that i can publish my app on the android market ?!

Comment: MY PROBLEM IS SOLVED.... i don't see my own Ads on my app cause my phone is Rooted / ROM Flashed...

Comment: Nice to see you finnaly did it ;) Consider choosing an answer for your question or put yourself an answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ads will not display if there is not enough room to in the layout.  Check the logcat log for any and all ad related messages. See this [Admob ads not showing - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616355/admob-ads-not-showing-android) for suggestions if this is the case.