# Admob Ads impossible to load

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I am very desesperated !! 
I am trying to implement Admob Ads in my application... but it's an epic fail... i am wasting more time on implementing Admob than coding my application... i really need your help please.

i give you all the informations :

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="package.test.sound"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/gg"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".startActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".test1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".test2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".test3"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:value="xxxx MY ID xxxx"     android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"></activity>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>

    </application>

    </manifest>
```

And now my Main.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/sc2"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center" >

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="test1"
        android:textColor="#005113" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="test2"
        android:textColor="#970000" />





    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="test3"
        android:textColor="#001760" />
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxx MY ID xxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

i don't know what to do...

I am using Admob SDK 4.3.1 and my project properties is on Android 4.0.3 !!
My project target is set to : target=android-15.

And one more thing... when i install my APK on my HTC EVO 3D, the application is not in FULL SCREEN, it is little on my screen, i don't know why too...

But my first big big problem is that Ads are not showing up...

And when i emulate my application with AVD emulator on eclipse i have this screen on LogCats debug : http://s4.noelshack.com/old/up/help-c2e97f1a28.jpg

Thank you for your help !!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077400/admob-ads-is-not-showing-up-admob-4-3-1

Comment: the answer is not working for me. Please help me instead :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you cannot connect with the admob servers.

You can verify this by trying to ping admob (media.admob.com according to your screenshot) from a terminal emulator in android.

Comment: MY PROBLEM IS SOLVED.... i don't see my own Ads on my app cause my phone is Rooted / ROM Flashed...

Comment: @dealswiss you should post solution as answer and make Green tick mark... so this solution will be more useful in future.. Thanks for sharing knowledge!!